# How to fix run time error in c++ , it's passing all the test cases except 1

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, fault

I am trying to find total number prime number in a range given by user [a,b], 
I am able to pass all the test cases except the last one and its showing run time error

```
int n1,n;
        cin>>n1>>n;
        bool prime[n+1];
        memset(prime,true,sizeof(prime));
        int i=2;
        while(i<=n)
        {
            if(prime[i]==true)
            {
                int j=i*i;
                while(j<=n)
                {
                    prime[j]=false;
                    j=j+i;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        prime[1]=false;
        i=n1;
        int temp=0;
        while(i<=n)
        {
            if(prime[i]==true)
            {
                temp++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        cout<<temp<<"\n";
```

The output is correct for all the given test cases but it's generating run time error for last case

Comment: Please show us your test cases. Also please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I am trying to solve this question, https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/find-prime/description/

Comment: A question must be "self contained". All relevant information should be *in* the question. *Not* behind external links.

Comment: `memset(prime,true,sizeof(prime));` - while `memset` in a C++ program *can* be correct, it is certainly always an odd thing to use. `std::fill` or just value initialization would be more common. Do you have a C background? Also, VLAs are *not* valid standard C++ (even if *some* compilers accept them (as extensions)).

Comment: Unless your `bool` has size one, and it probably doesn't, your `memset` is completely wrong – both the value and the size – and leads to undefined behaviour. I'm surprised that anything works at all.

Comment: I agree with @JesperJuhl, all the information should be in the question. Since you've narrowed down which test case is failing, surely it wouldn't be any trouble to hard-code values into `n`n and `n1`?

Comment: Sorry Jesper, will keep this is mind from next time, and yes i have a background in C

Comment: i tried various input and for 10001 1000001 it's showing run time error.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of non-standard variable length array in:

```
bool prime[n+1];
memset(prime,true,sizeof(prime));
```

which may overflow the stack if `n` is sufficiently large, do:

```
std::vector<bool> prime(n + 1, true);
```

The vector doesn't overflow the stack and stores 8 `bool` values in a byte.

---

It crashes on input 10001 1000001 because multiplication `i * i` overflows a 32-bit `int` when `i > 46341`. Replace `int` indexes with `long` (if `long` is at least 64-bit wide on your platform) or `int64_t` to fix. E.g.:

```
long f(long n1, long n) {
    std::vector<bool> prime(n + 1, true);
    for(long i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        if(prime[i])
            for(long j = i * i; j <= n; j += i)
                prime[j] = false;
    }
    prime[1] = false;

    long temp = 0;
    for(long i = n1; i <= n; ++i)
        temp += prime[i];
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << f(10001, 1000001) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Addendum: `std::vector<bool>` isn't like ordinary `vector`s, so it's a worth a look-through [of some good documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) to familiarize yourself with the differences..

Comment: I tried using vector and still it's having the same error for the input 10001 1000001

Comment: @NileshKumar Added a fix for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i understood my mistake.